# Sparse vector with extra metadata (python NumPy)

Tags: python, data-science, sparse-matrix, k-means, markov-chains

I have a dataset, where one row looks like this (g_1 to g_n are dynamic columns with integer value):

```
["day_of_week", "hour_of_day", "timestamp"     , g_1, g_2, g_3, ... , g_n]
[       2,            3,       2021-06-05 13:00, 4,   23,  100, ... , 12 ]
```

The idea is to transform only dynamic columns of each row to **sparse vector** and somehow attach metadata (day_of_week, hour_of_day) to it. After that I would use those sparse vectors to perform **k-means** and **markov-chains** (based on calculated clusters).
I need the metadata at the end to print out some information.

The question is: How to attach metadata to sparse vectors in python, or, does there exist any better approach to figure out which metadata belongs to each sparse vector after performing clustering and markov chains?

Comment: Why not use sparse columns in a pandas dataframe and cast them to a scipy sparse matrix when you want to use them in sklearn?

Comment: But after converting pandas dataframe to sparse matrix I lose metadata inside sparse matrix, right? Point is that after clustering I can check metadata of each vector :) For example: after performing k-means we get cluster with 10 vectors and for each of vectors we can find out metadata

Comment: You can trivially add the cluster IDs to your dataframe. You can also try the anndata package which keeps track of array metadata

Comment: Your use of **sparse vector** is unclear.  I'm familiar with the `scipy.sparse` matrices.  But then I'm not familiar with the k-means and chains software either.